# The conflict is caused by: The user requested tensorboard==2.1.0 tensorflow 1.15.4 depends on tensorboard<1.16.0 and >=1.15.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, pytorch, tensorboard

I am trying to install a package VIBE from a git repo and inistally I was installing its dependencies. The code is located here: https://github.com/mkocabas/VIBE how should I fix this?

Here's the error I got:

```
(vibe-env) mona@mona:~/research/VIBE$ pip install -r requirements.txt
Requirement already satisfied: numpy==1.17.5 in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/vibe-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)) (1.17.5)
Requirement already satisfied: torchvision==0.5.0 in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/vibe-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 19)) (0.5.0)
Collecting git+https://github.com/mattloper/chumpy.git (from -r requirements.txt (line 24))
  Cloning https://github.com/mattloper/chumpy.git to /tmp/pip-req-build-vdh2h3jw
Collecting git+https://github.com/mkocabas/yolov3-pytorch.git (from -r requirements.txt (line 25))
  Cloning https://github.com/mkocabas/yolov3-pytorch.git to /tmp/pip-req-build-ay_gkil2
Collecting git+https://github.com/mkocabas/multi-person-tracker.git (from -r requirements.txt (line 26))
  Cloning https://github.com/mkocabas/multi-person-tracker.git to /tmp/pip-req-build-l9jgk1qb
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.11.0 in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/vibe-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from chumpy==0.70->-r requirements.txt (line 24)) (1.15.0)
Collecting filterpy==1.4.5
  Using cached filterpy-1.4.5-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: numpy==1.17.5 in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/vibe-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)) (1.17.5)
Collecting gdown==3.6.4
  Downloading gdown-3.6.4.tar.gz (5.2 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.11.0 in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/vibe-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from chumpy==0.70->-r requirements.txt (line 24)) (1.15.0)
Collecting h5py==2.10.0
  Using cached h5py-2.10.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.9 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.11.0 in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/vibe-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from chumpy==0.70->-r requirements.txt (line 24)) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy==1.17.5 in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/vibe-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)) (1.17.5)
Collecting joblib==0.14.1
  Downloading joblib-0.14.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (294 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 294 kB 5.6 MB/s 
Collecting llvmlite==0.32.1
  Downloading llvmlite-0.32.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (20.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 20.2 MB 14.1 MB/s 
Collecting matplotlib==3.1.3
  Using cached matplotlib-3.1.3-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (13.1 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy==1.17.5 in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/vibe-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)) (1.17.5)
Collecting numba==0.47.0
  Downloading numba-0.47.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (3.7 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 3.7 MB 33.0 MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/vibe-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from numba==0.47.0->-r requirements.txt (line 6)) (51.0.0.post20201207)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy==1.17.5 in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/vibe-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)) (1.17.5)
Collecting opencv-python==4.1.2.30
  Downloading opencv_python-4.1.2.30-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (28.3 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 28.3 MB 29.4 MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: numpy==1.17.5 in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/vibe-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)) (1.17.5)
Collecting pillow==6.2.1
  Downloading Pillow-6.2.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.1 MB 107.9 MB/s 
Collecting progress==1.5
  Downloading progress-1.5.tar.gz (5.8 kB)
Collecting pyrender==0.1.36
  Downloading pyrender-0.1.36-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.2 MB 23.0 MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: numpy==1.17.5 in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/vibe-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)) (1.17.5)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.11.0 in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/vibe-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from chumpy==0.70->-r requirements.txt (line 24)) (1.15.0)
Collecting PyYAML==5.3.1
  Using cached PyYAML-5.3.1-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
Collecting scikit-image==0.16.2
  Downloading scikit_image-0.16.2-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (26.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 26.5 MB 25.7 MB/s 
Collecting scikit-video==1.1.11
  Using cached scikit_video-1.1.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.3 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy==1.17.5 in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/vibe-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)) (1.17.5)
Collecting scipy==1.4.1
  Using cached scipy-1.4.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (26.1 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy==1.17.5 in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/vibe-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)) (1.17.5)
Collecting smplx==0.1.13
  Downloading smplx-0.1.13-py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: torch>=1.0.1.post2 in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/vibe-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from smplx==0.1.13->-r requirements.txt (line 7)) (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy==1.17.5 in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/vibe-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)) (1.17.5)
Collecting tensorboard==2.1.0
  Downloading tensorboard-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (3.8 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 3.8 MB 29.3 MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/vibe-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from numba==0.47.0->-r requirements.txt (line 6)) (51.0.0.post20201207)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy==1.17.5 in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/vibe-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)) (1.17.5)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.11.0 in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/vibe-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from chumpy==0.70->-r requirements.txt (line 24)) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.26 in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/vibe-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tensorboard==2.1.0->-r requirements.txt (line 18)) (0.36.1)
Collecting tensorflow==1.15.4
  Downloading tensorflow-1.15.4-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (110.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 110.5 MB 22 kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: numpy==1.17.5 in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/vibe-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)) (1.17.5)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.11.0 in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/vibe-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from chumpy==0.70->-r requirements.txt (line 24)) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.26 in /home/mona/anaconda3/envs/vibe-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tensorboard==2.1.0->-r requirements.txt (line 18)) (0.36.1)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of tensorboard to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of smplx to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of scipy to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of scikit-video to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of scikit-image to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of pyyaml to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of pyrender to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of progress to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of pillow to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of opencv-python to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of numpy to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of numba to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of multi-person-tracker to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of matplotlib to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of llvmlite to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of joblib to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of h5py to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of gdown to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of filterpy to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of chumpy to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
ERROR: Cannot install -r requirements.txt (line 17) and tensorboard==2.1.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    The user requested tensorboard==2.1.0
    tensorflow 1.15.4 depends on tensorboard<1.16.0 and >=1.15.0

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies
```

```
(vibe-env) mona@mona:~/research/VIBE$ python
Python 3.7.9 (default, Aug 31 2020, 12:42:55) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>> torch.__version__
'1.4.0'
```

Here are all the commands I ran before this:

```
(base) mona@mona:~/research/VIBE$ export CONDA_ENV_NAME=vibe-env


(base) mona@mona:~/research/VIBE$ conda create -n $CONDA_ENV_NAME python=3.7


(base) mona@mona:~/research/VIBE$ eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"


(base) mona@mona:~/research/VIBE$ conda activate $CONDA_ENV_NAME

(vibe-env) mona@mona:~/research/VIBE$ pip install numpy==1.17.5 torch==1.4.0 torchvision==0.5.0

(vibe-env) mona@mona:~/research/VIBE$ pip install git+https://github.com/giacaglia/pytube.git --upgrade
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key here is this:

```
The conflict is caused by:
    The user requested tensorboard==2.1.0
    tensorflow 1.15.4 depends on tensorboard<1.16.0 and >=1.15.0
```

This is due to the fact that there is a conflict in `requirements.txt` of https://github.com/mkocabas/VIBE since it requires `tensorboard==2.1.0` and `tensorflow==1.15.4`. However, according to the error message, this version of `tensorflow` only works with `tensorboard 1.15.0 - 1.15.x`.

If you read the error closely you will see that `pip` itself suggests how to resolve this:

> To fix this you could try to:
>
> 1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
> 2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

Answer (score 1):

I removed the lines for installing tensorflow and tensorboard. I might end up with another problem later but current issue is resolved

```
$ bat requirements.txt 
───────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
       │ File: requirements.txt
───────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1   │ tqdm==4.28.1
   2   │ yacs==0.1.6
   3   │ h5py==2.10.0
   4   │ numpy==1.17.5
   5   │ scipy==1.4.1
   6   │ numba==0.47.0
   7   │ smplx==0.1.13
   8   │ gdown==3.6.4
   9   │ PyYAML==5.3.1
  10   │ joblib==0.14.1
  11   │ pillow==6.2.1
  12   │ trimesh==3.5.25
  13   │ pyrender==0.1.36
  14   │ progress==1.5
  15   │ filterpy==1.4.5
  16 _ │ matplotlib==3.1.3
  17   │ torchvision==0.5.0
  18   │ scikit-image==0.16.2
  19   │ scikit-video==1.1.11
  20   │ opencv-python==4.1.2.30
  21   │ llvmlite==0.32.1
  22   │ git+https://github.com/mattloper/chumpy.git
  23   │ git+https://github.com/mkocabas/yolov3-pytorch.git
  24   │ git+https://github.com/mkocabas/multi-person-tracker.git
```

Answer (score 0):

From error message, you should open requirements.txt, and find tensorboard version at line 17 and change version to 1.15.0