# I can't install Tensorflow Model Maker on Apple Silicon

Tags: tensorflow, pip, tensorflow-lite, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I have the Apple M1 Pro chip and cannot get my tensorflow project running. I followed the installation instructions from [Apple's site](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/).

When I run `pip install -r requirements.txt`, all my python packages install except for `tflite-model-maker`. I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Cannot install -r requirements.txt (line 19) and tflite-support because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    tflite-model-maker 0.3.4 depends on tensorflow>=2.6.0
    tflite-model-maker 0.3.3 depends on tensorflow>=2.6.0
    tflite-model-maker 0.3.2 depends on tensorflow>=2.4.0
    tflite-model-maker 0.3.1 depends on tensorflow>=2.4.0
    tflite-model-maker 0.3.0 depends on tensorflow>=2.4.0
    tflite-model-maker 0.2.5 depends on tensorflow>=2.4.0
    The user requested tflite-support
    tflite-model-maker 0.2.4 depends on tflite-support==0.1.0rc4
    tflite-model-maker 0.2.3 depends on tf-nightly==2.4.0.dev20200902
    tflite-model-maker 0.2.2 depends on tf-nightly==2.4.0.dev20200902
    tflite-model-maker 0.2.1 depends on tf-nightly==2.4.0.dev20200811
    tflite-model-maker 0.2.0 depends on tf-nightly==2.4.0.dev20200810
    tflite-model-maker 0.1.2 depends on tf-nightly
    The user requested tflite-support
    tflite-model-maker 0.1.1 depends on tflite-support==0.1.0a0
    The user requested tflite-support
    tflite-model-maker 0.1.0 depends on tflite-support==0.1.0a0

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Found a similar issue, did you try as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65226693/the-conflict-is-caused-by-the-user-requested-tensorboard-2-1-0-tensorflow-1-15)?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, the official release of tflite_model_maker doesn't support M1 chip yet.

But you can convert your model without installing the library:

1- Install TensorFlow: I used this tutorial: works perfectly: https://sudhanva.me/install-tensorflow-on-apple-m1-pro-max/

2- create your model using Keras os load it:

```
import tensorflow
model = tensorflow.keras.models.load_model(load_weights)
```

3- Convert your model to tflite:

```
converter = tensorflow.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()

with open('new_model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(tflite_model)
```